# How do I configure the listener binding address for python 2.7 smtplib running in a windows environment?

Tags: smtp, python, email-bounces

I am setting up an application called openemm which uses the python 2.7 smtplib to handle smtp transactions. My outgoing mail works fine but smtplib is not responding to incoming requests on port 25 (which are used to handle delayed bounces and I suspect delivery reports because none of it is working). I have tried various means to connect including telnet and always receive a 'no response from server' result. However, when I use TCPView, I can see that Python is listening on port 25.

The closet thing to a possible solution to this is a reference someone made to a similar issue saying "The other common thing is listening only on localhost, though because you have set 0.0.0.0 as the binding address that shouldn't be the problem."

I have searched around looking for a way to set the binding address for the listening port for smtplib with no success. I am new to Python and smtplib so any help here would be hugely appreciated.

UPDATE: I have figured out that I can telnet to the server from localhost so it is just ignoring connections from the internet. I assume there must be a way to configure it to accept connections from any address and I can then use windows firewall to limit connections to only my smart host.

Comment: Can you connect to it from the local host?

Comment: Yes...just figured out that I can connect locally but that doesn't help when I need to handle the bounced messages returned from my smart host.

Comment: It's time to start checking your firewalls, then.

Comment: I have inbound rules specifically allowing communication on port 25 for public, private and domain. I have enabled window default smtp allow for public, private and domain, I have tried all combinations of those rules and have completely turned off windows firewall with no success. I also called AT&T to ensure that my business class Uverse port 25 wasn't being blocked and ensured that my public subnet static ip was set to allow traffic from public. Now I am trying to figure out a way to test in incoming port 25 request with a different application like windows SMTP server.

Comment: I finally figured out the problem. It was the firewall rule created to allow port 25 requests. The rule was associated with SMTP service and despite that being what I was allowing, it was not the windows SMTP service so it was blocking it.